# PHPMailer character encoding issues

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I try to use PHPMailer to send registration, activation. etc mail to users:

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail -> charSet = "UTF-8";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();  
$mail->Host     = "smtp.mydomain.org";  
$mail->From     = "name@mydomain.org";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username ="username"; 
$mail->Password="passw"; 
//$mail->FromName = $header;
$mail->FromName = mb_convert_encoding($header, "UTF-8", "auto");
$mail->AddAddress($emladd);
$mail->AddAddress("mytest@gmail.com");
$mail->AddBCC('mytest2@mydomain.org', 'firstadd');
$mail->Subject  = $sub;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;  
if(!$mail->Send()) {  
   echo 'Message was not sent.';  
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;  
}
```

The `$message` contains latin characters. Unfortunately all webmail (gmail, webmail.mydomain.org, emailaddress.domain.xx) is using a different coding.

How can I force to use UTF-8 coding to show my mail exactly the same on all mailboxes?

I tried to convert the mail header width `mb_convert_encoding()`, but without luck.

Comment: Capitalization of CharSet above was changed by bovender.

Answer (score 630, accepted):

If you are 100% sure $message contain ISO-8859-1 you can use [utf8_encode](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) as David says. Otherwise use  [mb_detect_encoding](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and [mb_convert_encoding](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) on $message.

Also take note that

```
$mail -> charSet = "UTF-8";
```

Should be replaced by:

```
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
```

**And** placed **after** the instantiation of the class (after the `new`). The properties are case sensitive! See the [PHPMailer doc](http://www.phpmailer.me/index.php?pg=properties) fot the list & exact spelling.

Also the default encoding of PHPMailer is `8bit` which can be problematic with UTF-8 data. To fix this you can do:

```
$mail->Encoding = 'base64';
```

Take note that `'quoted-printable'` would probably work too in these cases (and maybe even `'binary'`). For more details you can read [RFC1341 - Content-Transfer-Encoding Header Field](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html).

Comment: It is very strange that just this statement was the root cause of the problem, mail was not being sent (but there were no error at all) `$message += '\n\nThis message was sent from IP Address: `. Once I replaced += with .= the emails started getting sent.

Comment: The `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` trick is still valid as of version 6.5. What a shame that 1. ISO-8859-1 is still the default charset in the PHPMailer class and 2. There's no public method that sets the CharSet public class variable, hence hinting your IDE that such an option exists...

Comment: You can also make use of PHPMailer's built-in UTF-8 constant: `$mailer->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;`. If you look at the [source code of PHPMailer.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/9952101e44219a6b1c3055a4d7fe1cd1a9792b2c/src/PHPMailer.php#L32-L77), you'll see the available constants and that by default (at the time of writing, version 6.8.1) `CHARSET_ISO88591` is used.

Answer (score 37):

```
$mail -> CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

line `$mail -> CharSet = "UTF-8";` must be after `$mail = new PHPMailer();`

try this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
```

Comment: I updated this post for better reading, but the op's question was already answered 2 years before! And that accepted answere included this one already.

Answer (score 7):

I work myself this way

```
  $mail->FromName = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Comment: Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for being late on the party. Depending on your server configuration, You may be required to specify character strictly with **lowercase letters** utf-8, otherwise it will be ignored. Try this if you end up here searching for solutions and none of answers above helps:

```
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
```

should be replaced with:

```
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
```

Comment: The standard has it always in uppercase, if it matters.

Answer (score 6):

When non of the above works, and still mails looks like `ª ×”×•×“×¤×¡×” ×•× ×©×œ`:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8');
$mail->Subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';;
```

Comment: Worked for me with Apache, Encoding ISO-8859-1 under Windows with MS Outlook Client

Answer (score 3):

I was getting **&oacute;** in $mail->Subject /w PHPMailer.

So for me the complete solution is:

```
// Your Subject with tildes. Example.
$someSubjectWithTildes = 'Subscripción España';

$mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mailer->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';
$mailer->Subject = html_entity_decode($someSubjectWithTildes);
```

Hope it helps.